# writing command line output to text file

Tags: java, linux, command-line

As there's simple way to write result to output file using `> <outputfule.txt>` but this does not work in my case

I have client server kind of scenario, where first I start the server -

```
java -mx500m -cp stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz &
```

Now server is in listening mode. Here I am starting client instant where I have issue.

```
java -cp stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -client
```

This ask to entere the input sentence and prints result on command line on pressing enter. I tried in this way

```
java -cp stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -client > result.txt
```

which stops client instant. I am ok if it read input from text file and write it to resultant text file.

What is correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you want you can redirect both standard input and standard output at the same time:

```
java -cp stanford.jar NERServer -port 9191 -client < input.txt > result.txt
```

Or do something like this:

```
echo -e "line1\nline2" | java -cp stanford.jar NERServer -port 9191 -client > r.txt
```

When doing input/output redirection the application runs exactly the same way as if the input/output would not be redirected.

It does not know or care if you type the input from the keyboard or this is redirected from somewhere.
So it will always print same things to the standard output (in your case)

> press RETURN to NER tag it, or just RETURN to finish

There is nothing that you can do about this apart from throwing away the first line from the results.txt when you interpret them.

Comment: thanks, this is what I needed, but apart from writing result, it also writes message `Input some text and press RETURN to NER tag it, or just RETURN to finish`

Comment: this is the message, which get printed on commandline when user execute client command

Comment: that is one of the way, throwing firstline from result out. IS that possible to extract code from jar and changing the code?

Comment: It is possible to decompile the binary classes in the jar and then make changes, or even change the class at the bytecode level. But I guess that this is an opensource project, so if you want the change it just download the source, make your change and rebuild it.

Comment: yeah, it is opensource but I guess only jar is available, no source code I could find

Comment: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERServer.java

Comment: thanks, it was what expected. But it could not be imported as a project in eclipes.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your query correctly, you expect

"
java -cp stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -client
"

to take input from "result.txt".

In that case, your should execute

"java -cp stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -client < result.txt"

**Corrected Reply:**

Then you should try this .

"java -cp stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -client < x.txt > y.txt"

Where you read input from x.txt and write output to y.txt

Comment: sorry, you took it in wrong way, I want to result from file x.txt and want to write result to y.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo "input sequence" | xargs java -cp stanford.jar NERServer -port 9191 -client > result.txt
```

This would be for redirecting command with parameters to the file.

If you simply want to pass arguments to a command, than you just need

```
java -cp stanford.jar NERServer -port 9191 -client < result.txt`
```

or

```
cat params.txt | xargs java -cp stanford.jar NERServer -port 9191 -client
```

`xargs` should send your parameters from the file to the `java` program

P.S. I omitted the package names for the sake of brevity and readability

Comment: thanks dear, but here there's issue. When I followed first command, rather then writing output to `result.txt`it writes msg `Input some text and press RETURN to NER tag it,  or just RETURN to finish.`. This is the message which is showed on commandline when client command gets exected